# Django model migrate two tables

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a review site, writen in Django,..

How can I migrate a model to obtain review data -

I have a product class and a vendor class, and finaly a review class with review for both products and vendors:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ....

class Vendor(models.Model):
    ....

class Review(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ReviewImage, blank=True, null=True)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    review = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When i select a product or a vendor I need the AVG rating from the REVIEW class... How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [django docs on annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations).

Something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
qs = Vendor.objects.annotate(rating_avg=Avg('review__rating'))
```

Then each vendor in `qs` will have a `.rating_avg` property.

Comment: vendor_list = Vendor.objects.filter(category=category, review__product__isnull=True, active=True).annotate(rating_avg=Avg('review__rating'))  HOW can I do it with "review__product__isnull=True" ?? If there is no review, there is no vendor... what to do?